# Basic Rails3 routes question?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

My `routes.rb` has the following 2 lines:

```
match "/",          :to => "main#index"
match "main/index", :to => "main#index"
```

When I type `localhost:3000/main/index` in a browser I see the proper page (`views/main/index.html.erb`).

However, if I type just `localhost:3000` I see `public/index.html` (I expect to see `views/main/index.html.erb` as well).

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `public/index.html`:

```
rm public/index.html
```

This is happening because static files (those in `public/`) are served in priority to the routes.